# XMLSyntaxError:Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding,Odoo

Tags: python, xml, utf-8, odoo

I am creating a module on odoo local(offline). To create it, it requires Model(in python) and View(in Xml). The module will then be installed, but an error occurred after creating the view.

This is the view.xml

```
<openerp>
<data> 
<record id="view_form_todo_task_inherited" model="ir.ui.view">
   <field name="name">Todo Task form – User extension</field>
   <field name="model">todo.task</field>
   <field name="inherit_id" ref="todo_app.view_form_todo_task"/>
   <field name="arch" type="xml">
      <field name="name" position="after">
         <field name="user_id" />
      </field>
      <field name="is_done" position="before">
         <field name="date_deadline" />
      </field>
      <field name="name" position="attributes">
         <attribute name="string">I have to...<attribute/>
      </field>
   </field>
</record>
</data>
</openerp>`
```

in creating the view it is important to make it inside `<data>` that is inside `<openerp>` otherwise it  wont work.

When trying to install the module(which also will compile the codes), an error occurred and it indicates that there is something wrong with the view.xml file.
It says

`XMLSyntaxError: Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !
Bytes: 0x96 0x20 0x55 0x73, line 4, column 28`

here is the traceback

```
`    Odoo Server Error
      Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "D:\Bitnami\odoo-8.0-12\apps\odoo\Lib\site-packages\odoo-8.0_20150423-py2.7.egg\openerp\http.py", line 530, in _handle_exception
     return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
     File "D:\Bitnami\odoo-8.0-12\apps\odoo\Lib\site-packages\odoo-8.0_20150423-py2.7.egg\openerp\http.py", line 567, in dispatch
     result = self._call_function(**self.params)
     File "D:\Bitnami\odoo-8.0-12\apps\odoo\Lib\site-packages\odoo-8.0_20150423-py2.7.egg\openerp\http.py", line 303, in _call_function
     return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
     File "D:\Bitnami\odoo-8.0-12\apps\odoo\Lib\site-packages\odoo-8.0_20150423-py2.7.egg\openerp\service\model.py", line 113, in wrapper
     return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
     File "D:\Bitnami\odoo-8.0-12\apps\odoo\Lib\site-packages\odoo-8.0_20150423-py2.7.egg\openerp\http.py", line 300, in checked_call
     return self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
     File "D:\Bitnami\odoo-8.0-12\apps\odoo\Lib\site-packages\odoo-8.0_20150423-py2.7.egg\openerp\http.py", line 796, in __call__
     return self.method(*args, **kw)
     File "D:\Bitnami\odoo-8.0-12\apps\odoo\Lib\site-packages\odoo-8.0_20150423-py2.7.egg\openerp\http.py", line 396, in response_wrap
     response = f(*args, **kw)
     File "D:\Bitnami\odoo-8.0-12\apps\odoo\Lib\site-packages\odoo-8.0_20150423-py2.7.egg\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 940, in call_button
     action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
     File "D:\Bitnami\odoo-8.0-12\apps\odoo\Lib\site-packages\odoo-8.0_20150423-py2.7.egg\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 928, in _call_kw
     return getattr(request.registry.get(model), method)(request.cr, request.uid, *args, **kwargs)
     File "D:\Bitnami\odoo-8.0-12\apps\odoo\Lib\site-packages\odoo-8.0_20150423-py2.7.egg\openerp\api.py", line 241, in wrapper
     return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
     File "D:\Bitnami\odoo-8.0-12\apps\odoo\Lib\site-packages\odoo-8.0_20150423-py2.7.egg\openerp\addons\base\module\module.py", line 450, in button_immediate_install
     return self._button_immediate_function(cr, uid, ids, self.button_install, context=context)
     File "D:\Bitnami\odoo-8.0-12\apps\odoo\Lib\site-packages\odoo-8.0_20150423-py2.7.egg\openerp\api.py", line 241, in wrapper
     return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
     File "D:\Bitnami\odoo-8.0-12\apps\odoo\Lib\site-packages\odoo-8.0_20150423-py2.7.egg\openerp\addons\base\module\module.py", line 498, in _button_immediate_function
     registry = openerp.modules.registry.RegistryManager.new(cr.dbname, update_module=True)
     File "D:\Bitnami\odoo-8.0-12\apps\odoo\Lib\site-packages\odoo-8.0_20150423-py2.7.egg\openerp\modules\registry.py", line 368, in new
openerp.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
     File "D:\Bitnami\odoo-8.0-12\apps\odoo\Lib\site-packages\odoo-8.0_20150423-py2.7.egg\openerp\modules\loading.py", line 355, in load_modules
loaded_modules, update_module)
     File "D:\Bitnami\odoo-8.0-12\apps\odoo\Lib\site-packages\odoo-8.0_20150423-py2.7.egg\openerp\modules\loading.py", line 255, in load_marked_modules
loaded, processed = load_module_graph(cr, graph, progressdict, report=report, skip_modules=loaded_modules, perform_checks=perform_checks)
     File "D:\Bitnami\odoo-8.0-12\apps\odoo\Lib\site-packages\odoo-8.0_20150423-py2.7.egg\openerp\modules\loading.py", line 176, in load_module_graph
_load_data(cr, module_name, idref, mode, kind='data')
      File "D:\Bitnami\odoo-8.0-12\apps\odoo\Lib\site-packages\odoo-8.0_20150423-py2.7.egg\openerp\modules\loading.py", line 118, in _load_data
tools.convert_file(cr, module_name, filename, idref, mode, noupdate, kind, report)
      File "D:\Bitnami\odoo-8.0-12\apps\odoo\Lib\site-packages\odoo-8.0_20150423-py2.7.egg\openerp\tools\convert.py", line 901, in convert_file
convert_xml_import(cr, module, fp, idref, mode, noupdate, report)
      File "D:\Bitnami\odoo-8.0-12\apps\odoo\Lib\site-packages\odoo-8.0_20150423-py2.7.egg\openerp\tools\convert.py", line 974, in convert_xml_import
doc = etree.parse(xmlfile)
      File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 3299, in lxml.etree.parse (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:72421)
      File "parser.pxi", line 1812, in lxml.etree._parseDocument (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:106108)
      File "parser.pxi", line 1832, in lxml.etree._parseFilelikeDocument (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:106368)
      File "parser.pxi", line 1727, in lxml.etree._parseDocFromFilelike (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:105258)
      File "parser.pxi", line 1146, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDocFromFilelike (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:100385)
      File "parser.pxi", line 580, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:94254)
       File "parser.pxi", line 690, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:95690)
       File "parser.pxi", line 620, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:94757)
     XMLSyntaxError: Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !
     Bytes: 0x96 0x20 0x55 0x73, line 4, column 28`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reformatted your xml to better check it and I noticed two things:
1. the *data* tag was missing
2. there where two "'" characters at the beginning and at the end of your xml. Because your trace says "Input is not proper UTF-8" it occurs to me that the problem could be given by this very same character.

Check in yor source file if they are there as well and remove them, then add the *data* tag as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
<data> 
<record id="view_form_todo_task_inherited" model="ir.ui.view">
   <field name="name">Todo Task form – User extension</field>
   <field name="model">todo.task</field>
   <field name="inherit_id" ref="todo_app.view_form_todo_task"/>
   <field name="arch" type="xml">
      <data>
         <field name="name" position="after">
            <field name="user_id" />
         </field>
         <field name="is_done" position="before">
            <field name="date_deadline" />
         </field>
         <field name="name" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="string">I have to...</attribute>
         </field>
      </data>
   </field>
</record>
</data>
</openerp>
```

Comment: i did put the following line, still gives the same error

Comment: The ` character wasn't included in my view.xml, it was my mistake posting the code here --> `enter your code` (added " ` " by mistake). And I just realized that the closing of attribute was wrongly written `<attribute/>` that is supposed to be `</attribute>`, your answer made me realize that. Thanks ,

Comment: jeez I didn't notice while writing that :D